# Is there any alternative to DateTime.Ticks or DateTime.TimeOfDay in Linq-To-Entities?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm writing a log parser for an asp.net mvc2 web application. I use Entity framework as a model and logging is done both using my manual engine together with SqlServer2008 CDC feature.

When inserting, or editing a row in a database, the action is being logged. However, there's a small lag between occuring changes in actual table and logging those changes. I need to display details from CDC tables, when user clicks on some of them. Because of before mentioned lag, I can not compare equivalence of two DateTime values. I want to allow lag of 2000 miliseconds. Easiest way I know is using Ticks, or TimeOfDay and comparing absolute value of their values subtracted, but damned Linq-To-Entities does not allow these two properties.

Here's the simple function I'm having problems with...

```
        public static List<dbo_Object_CT> GetLogDetails (Int32 objectID, DateTime? actionDateAndTime)
    {
        ObjectEntities oe = new ObjectEntities();

        var mylogdetails = (from objectLog in oe.dbo_Object_CT
                     join ltm in oe.lsn_time_mapping on objectLog.C___start_lsn equals ltm.start_lsn
                     where (objectLog.Id == objectID)
                     && ((actionDateAndTime == null) ? true : (Math.Abs(actionDateAndTime.Value.Ticks - ltm.tran_begin_time.Value.Ticks) < 2000))
                     select objectLog).ToList();

        return mylogdetails;
    }
```

I know I could manually do "where" clause, but it would be big, ugly and slow. Does anyone have better sugestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [EF Canonical functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563(VS.100).aspx) and [SQL Server-specific functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399545.aspx). Here is a couple of guides on how to use these functions: 
[How to: Call Canonical Functions (LINQ to Entities)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456873.aspx) 
[How to: Call Database Functions (LINQ to Entities)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456858.aspx) 
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx) you can find some information concerning the EntityFunctions class.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
((TimeSpan) (actionDateAndTime.Value - ltm.tran_begin_time.Value)).Milliseconds > 2000
```

Produces SQL something like

```
(CONVERT(Int,(CONVERT(BigInt,(CONVERT(BigInt,(((
 CONVERT(BigInt,DATEDIFF(DAY, t1, t2))) 
 * 86400000) 
 + DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, t1, t2), t1), t2)) 
 * 10000)) / 10000)) % 1000))
```

Don't know how to get LINQ to produce sql like

```
 DATEDIFF (MS , actionDateAndTime , ltm.tran_begin_time)
```

Comment: I'm trying something similar, although, "TotalMiliseconds" must be used, because "Miliseconds" returns only Miliseconds part of the DateTime (and when you subtract DateTime from DateTime, you also get DateTime)

For now I'm unsuccessful, if I succeed I'll report (and vote up, of course ;))

Comment: Oops. Forgot about TotalMilliseconds vs Milliseconds.
Also forgot you need Math.Abs(..)